# Magento 2 Dropdown for Quantity instead of text box

Tags: magento2, addtocart, quantity

I tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz1z5.png) solution it worked perfectly for me on my Magento 2.2.9. I just wish to extend it with the below functionality -

1. Quantities for the drop-down to pick up from the Tier Prices for the product.
2. Show the Qty and its respective tier price such as "1 for $10", "2 for $18", etc.
3. Increase the size of the quantity field so that the quantity and price both are properly shown in the box.

[UPDATE]

I tried with below code. Although, I see the page quantity dropdown does not show up. What could I be doing wrong? However, if I select another product which does not have tier prices, shows as expected.

Product with Tier Prices set -

[image]

Product without Tier Prices set -

[image]

```php
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */


?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>               
            <select name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" 
                   class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">
                   <?php $i = 1 ; ?>
                    <?php 
                        $qtyOptions = $_product->getTierPrices();
//                        var_dump($qtyOptions);
                        if(count($qtyOptions) > 0): ?>
                            <div>
                            <span> Qty.\tPrice\tCust.Group ( <?php echo escapeHtml(json_encode($qtyOptions)); print_r(escapeHtml(json_encode($qtyOptions))); ?> )</span>
                            <?php
                            echo "price_qty\tprice\tCustomerGroupId\n";
                            foreach ($qtyOptions as $price) { 
                                $q = $price->getQty();
                                $p = $price->getValue();
                                $g = $price->getCustomerGroupId();
                                print_r($price->getData());
                                echo $q;
                                echo "\t";
                                echo $p;
                                echo "\t";
                                echo $g;
                            //    var_dump($qtyOptions, $q, $p, $g); ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $price->getQty(); ?>"><?php echo $price->getQty(); ?></option>
                                <span><?php echo $q; echo "\t"; echo $p; echo "\t"; echo $g; echo "\t"; ?></span>
                            <?php }
                        else:
                            while( $i < 9) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                                <?php $i++; 
                                }
                        endif ;

                    ?></div>
            </select>

        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>

}
```

Comment: are you looking for this extension?
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-tier-price.html
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-quantity-dropdown.html

Comment: I have seen these modules and also had discussed with the developers and they could not satisfy my questions and functionality that I am looking for. So, deciding to develop it myself and so looking for help if anyone could.